# Renaming files with Python doesn't show in Windows Explorer without refreshing (only changing capitalization)

Tags: python, file-rename, windows-explorer

I have a Python script to change the capitalization of multiple files in a directory. The problem is that I run my script but Windows Explorer doesn't show the new names unless I hit "refresh" with F5. I know Windows Explorer is essentially case insensitive so I think it doesn't recognize that there were changes to the directory if the only changes were to the capitalization.

For what it's worth, I run the script with that directory open in Windows Explorer so I expect to see the change in that opened window.

In the script, I have tried renaming the files to something intermediate (like `file_important_stuff.txt` to `test.txt` and then to the desired `File_Important_Stuff.txt`) but it seems that Windows 10 just compares the "before" and "after" names in the directory to decide whether to "refresh" or not. Same with moving the files to a different directory and then back within the script.

I can force the desired behavior if I use open() to open each renamed file for writing in Python but then the date modified changes, which I don't want.

**Edit**: Some new learning. If you rename one to four files, Windows Explorer will update. If you update 5 or more files, it doesn't refresh the window. Here is some same code:

```
import os

for x in range(1,6):
    fileNameOld = "file_important_stuff_" + str(x) + ".txt"
    fileNameNew = "File_Important_Stuff_" + str(x) + ".txt"
    os.rename(fileNameOld,fileNameNew)
```

[Here's a picture of the directory with the files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmwTu.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for here. Are you hoping to find some kind of Windows Explorer setting that changes this behavior?

Comment: If you just rename the file to `file_important_stuff.txt` to `test.txt`, does windows explorer refresh immediately? Also, windows explorer can be case sensitive, it's just that the file system of windows, NTFS is not case sensitive (but you can store the case (often)).

Comment: can you please provide the script so I can test? I suspect we may need to use `win32api` library to notify Windows Explorer of changes to the file system.

Comment: I am hoping for a Python function that might tell Windows to refresh or trigger Explorer in some way to get it to recognize that the filenames changed. I suppose it's more Windows related but I want the fix to be implemented into the Python script. 



When I change it from `file_important_stuff.txt` to `test.txt`, Windows Explorer refreshes immediately, as desired.

Comment: Added example code as requested. I also learned that if your script updates 5 or more files, then the behavior appears. Less than that and it works as desired (new file names show up immediately).

Answer (score 0):

`import os module` and add `os.system('gpupdate/force')` to force a system refresh

Comment: This did not work unfortunately but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Got help on the SuperUser site:

https://superuser.com/questions/1781550/windows-explorer-doesnt-show-updated-names-when-changing-capitalization-multip/1781580#1781580

This is the Powershell script that worked for me:

```
$windows = $(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()
$windows  | ? { $_.FullName -eq "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" -and $_.LocationURL -match "$path$" } | % { $_.Refresh() }
```